# jQuery - Changing label text based on radio click

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if it is possible with jQuery to change text on a page based on what radio button is clicked.

I have the following code, and i want to change the label text to "first radio was clicked" or "second radio was clicked" based on which of the radio buttons were clicked.

```
<input type="radio" name="first" value="yes" id="firstradio">
<input type="radio" name="first" value="no" id="secondradio"> 

<label class="changeme">Initial text goes here and is happy</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like below :

```
$('input[name=first]').change(function()  {
    // change the page per this logic
    switch ($('input[name=first]:checked').val()) {
        case 'yes':
            $('#Message').text('first radio was clicked'); break;
        case 'no':
            $('#Message').text('second radio was clicked'); break;
        default:
            $('#Message').text('select choice');
};
```

Comment: Were all those `#`s intentional?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':radio').click(function() {

   var index = $(this).index(),
       // Modify this to suit all ordinals
       ordinal = (index == 0) ? 'first' : 'second';    

   $('.changeme').text(ordinal + ' radio was clicked');

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7uAtZ/).

Comment: Thanks for this, i kind of want to hardcode the values in as there will be quite a few things that need changing, is there a if else statement in jquery, like - if firstradio is clicked then changeme becomes first radio was clicke and so on?

Comment: @BigJobbies You can make an array where the index of the radio maps to the index of the array member, which contains your text.

Answer (score 1):

For your code:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(evt) {
    $('.changeme').html($(this).val());
});
```

That'll change the label to whatever you put in that `value` attribute. For better results, I'd use class names on the radio buttons and ids on the labels you wish to change.

Edit: Here's [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/bsSpS/).

Comment: Is there a way i can predefine the text that goes in there? as i have a few labels to change at the same time?

Comment: Sure, here's an updated jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/bsSpS/1/. I'm using `data` attributes to do it, although that's by no means the only way to do it.

Comment: Interesting ... one more thing, how would i add the text to be changed to the actual jquery line, so that i could change several labels at the same time?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. But, you can create an array of labels that correspond to values in your javascript if you prefer, so that you have a "dictionary" of values to use, or you can store multiple `data` attributes per tag (`data-description`, `data-title`, `data-date`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
<asp:ListItem Value="C">Contract </asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem Value="I">Independent</asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="O">OutSource </asp:ListItem> </asp:RadioButtonList>  <br />
 <asp:Label ID="lblLaborType" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function ()     
     {   
      $("#<%=rbtnType.ClientID%>").change(function () 
    {    
      var rbvalue = $("input[@name=<%=rbtnType.ClientID%>]:radio:checked").val();   
        if (rbvalue == "C")
      {        
            $('#<%=lblLaborType.ClientID %>').html('Do this');  
   } 
      else if (rbvalue == "I")
   {         
      $('#<%=lblLaborType.ClientID %>').html('else this'); 
    }

    else if (rbvalue == "O") 
     {
           $('#<%=lblLaborType.ClientID %>').html('or else this');        
    }
    }); 
    }); 
   </script>
```