# Change text input name based on radio button selected

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 3 inputs:

- name
- email
- company

I also have two radio buttons a user must select from:

- A
- B

If the user selects A, leave the form fields as they are.  If the user selects B then change the descriptions of the input fields.

By default the form loads as A.

name = we want your (name), company = we want your (company), email = we want your (email)

How do I get the changed radio button value to update the text input fields?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? SO users are not rent-a-coders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Changing label text based on radio click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657592/jquery-changing-label-text-based-on-radio-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58km4/1/) as an example for this trick.
What you want to do is make the normal form, with two radio buttons, and bind the onChange event to them so whenever you click a radio button it triggers a check to see which radio button was clicked, and make changes to the form/mark-up around it.

example JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='option']").live("change", function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "A") {
         $("input.first-input").attr("name", "name");
         $("input.first-input").siblings("span").text("name:");  
         $("input.second-input").attr("name", "company");
         $("input.second-input").siblings("span").text("company:");  
         $("input.third-input").attr("name", "email");
         $("input.third-input").siblings("span").text("email:");                   
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "B") {
         $("input.first-input").attr("name", "color");
         $("input.first-input").siblings("span").text("color:");  
         $("input.second-input").attr("name", "width");
         $("input.second-input").siblings("span").text("width:");  
         $("input.third-input").attr("name", "height");
         $("input.third-input").siblings("span").text("height:");              
    }
});
```

});

test HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="option" value="A" checked="checked" /> A -- <input type="radio" name="option" value="B" /> B
<br />
<br />
<label><span>name:</span> <input type="text" name="name" class="first-input" /></label><br />
<label><span>company:</span> <input type="text" name="company" class="second-input" /></label><br />
<label><span>email:</span> <input type="text" name="email" class="third-input" /></label><br />
```